# How can I block system alert and show my custom screen instead

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I make an app that can connect to ble device. My ble device required pairing. Now when I connect to device - system shows me "Bluetooth Pairing Request" alert. But I wont to make custom code input screen for pairing action. How can I block system alert and show my custom screen instead.

Comment: well i dont know anything about iOS but i **guess** this wont be possible - one does not simply *"block"* system messages ... that would require modification of the operating system. With windows, this would be possible since Microsoft offers "custom pairing" options which hand over the user interaction to your own window handlers ... but you cant really compare windows to apple products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pairing (actually bonding) process is handled by iOS; there is no facility to allow your app to handle the pairing process.

Once you initiate an action on a characteristic that requires encryption (and therefore bonding) your app will resign the active state and the system pairing dialog will be presented to the user.  Once they have completed (or cancelled) the pairing process then your app will resume the active state.